# Channels are not running after the certificate renewal on MQ windows

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

We are trying to import the new renewed certs into keystore in MQ windows in our production but the channels are going to retying status after deploying the certs. Looks like somehow our queue manager is not reading the certs from the below error. The issuer of the certs are same before and now. The certs being used is rootCA5, serverCA5 and personal Cert. The channels are working fine when we put back the old certs. I have checked the permissions on the ssl folder and keystore, they are fine. Looking for some valuable suggestions as our old certs are going to expire tomorrow.The MQ version we are using is MQ7.1.0.7.

We tried to add the below parameters in qm.ini file and we faced the same issue yesterday.

```
SSL:
OCSPAuthentication=OPTIONAL
OCSPCheckExtensions=NO
```

The following error is logged in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG:

```
10/18/2017 19:29:45 - Process(3084.1) User(4055TMQU) Program(runmqchl.exe)
                      Host(abcdefgh) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.1.0.7) QMgr(QMPDBP)

AMQ9642: No SSL or TLS certificate for channel 'xxxxxx.yyyyyy'.

EXPLANATION:
The channel 'xxxxxx.yyyyyy' did not supply a certificate to use during SSL
or TLS handshaking, but a certificate is required by the remote queue manager. 

The remote host is 'abcdefgh (10.x.x.x)(1415)'. 

The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Ensure that the key repository of the local queue manager or MQ client contains
a certificate which is associated with the queue manager or client.
Alternatively, if appropriate, change the remote channel definition so that its
SSLCAUTH attribute is set to OPTIONAL and it has no SSLPEER value set.
```

Comment: Did you check that the label of the cert matches the string `ibmwebspheremqqmpdbp`?

Comment: @JoshMc, Exactly that was our issue. We had a wrong label.I edited the label. Hope now our certificates will work.

Comment: Rinak, I wrote up a answer with some more details, please accept and vote it up if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With IBM MQ v7.5 and lower the label of the queue manager certificate must be the exact string `ibmwebspheremq` concatenated with the queue manager name folded to lowercase.

Based on the error you posted I can see the queue manager name is `QMPDBP`, so check that the label of the certificate matches the string `ibmwebspheremqqmpdbp`

Note that with IBM MQ v8.0 and later you can tell the queue manager the name of the certificate label to use by setting the queue manager `CERTLABL` attribute, this defaults to the value which matches what was required in v7.5 and lower.

For example:

```
ALTER QMGR CERTLABL('DifferentLabel`)
```

Comment: Thank you for being more detail about the resolution. I have deployed the new certificates just now and the channels are running fine.